# How do I set up slave MySQL database for reporting purposes only?

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

Given a large MySQL production database, optimized for fast inserts, how would I go about setting up a "slave" database that would be optimized for fast searches? In my head, the slave would basically be a replica of the main, but with significantly more indices across the whole database to speed up read access. Is this sort of customized master-to-slave replication possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Setting up master/slave replication?

This [How to Set Up Replication in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-howto.html) guide has both what you need to do on the master and the slave.

Found here on [this MySQL Replication question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402794/mysql-replication):

Comment: My question relates more to how to modify the indices on the slave, and whether that's possible/easy/difficult to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue that you may want to consider an alternative database for your reporting side.  You mentioned the need for heavy indexes -- why?  Since I assume you're doing bulk loads of data and hardly modifying the data at all (ie: transactions), then you should consider a columnar database.  If you're used to mysql syntax, then there are two column-oriented databases which use mysql as a front end.  Thus, your queries will stay the same, but how the data is stored underneath will be completely different.

It really throws your question out and adds a new one in: what's the best way to move my data to allow it to be optimized for many reads and few writes.

Full Disclosure: I work as the open-source guy for Infobright (one of the column oriented techs).  Your question is one I see a lot of, so I thought I'd give you my thoughts.  However, there are several different columnar vendors; it all depends on volume, money, and time.